# Camel activemq component nosuchmethod exception

Tags: apache-camel, camel-jms

I am using activemq component to send/receive messages, however when I split() the body(), am getting this below exception.
I am using camel 2.23.0 version. can someone advise what is wrong?

This is an example of a route which causes this issue:

```
from("activemq:queue:aaa")
.process("myprocessor")
.split().body()
.to("activemq:queue:bbb")
```

I have no issues if I use this way:

```
from("activemq:queue:aaa")
.process("myprocessor")
```

Inside MyProcessor,

```
process(Exchange exchange) {
   for (String body : exchange.getIn().getBody(List.class)) {
     ProducerTemplate.sendBody("activemq:queue:bbb",body);
   }
 }
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsMessage.getCamelContext()Lorg/apache/camel/CamelContext;
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsMessage.newInstance(JmsMessage.java:195)
    at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsMessage.newInstance(JmsMessage.java:40)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.copy(MessageSupport.java:152)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.copy(DefaultExchange.java:116)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.copy(DefaultExchange.java:90)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.createCopy(ExchangeHelper.java:301)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.copyExchangeNoAttachments(Splitter.java:291)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.access$100(Splitter.java:56)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter$SplitterIterable.<init>(Splitter.java:158)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter$SplitterIterable.<init>(Splitter.java:144)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.createProcessorExchangePairsIterable(Splitter.java:141)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.createProcessorExchangePairsList(Splitter.java:245)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Splitter.createProcessorExchangePairs(Splitter.java:129)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:241)
```

Comment: Sounds a bit like you have mixed versions of Camel on your classpath. Can you check your dependencies and make sure you are only using the same version of Camel. And what ActiveMQ version are you using btw?

Answer (score 0):

Beside the potential classpath issues Claus Ibsen commented about, I wonder what you are trying to achieve.

Your `MyProcessor` iterates over the parts of the message body (a `List`) and sends each part to the queue `bbb`. Then you use a [Splitter](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/split-eip.adoc) in your Camel Route and send the parts to the queue `bbb`?

Doesn't your `MyProcessor` do the same as the rest of your Camel route?